# MySQL case statement with left join condition

Tags: mysql, case, case-when

I have a MySQL request below and it is not working right.

Error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'uid' in 'on clause'

Query:

```
SELECT 
  u.email,
  CASE 
  WHEN c.from_user_id = '301' THEN c.to_user_id 
  WHEN c.to_user_id = '301' THEN c.from_user_id 
  END AS uid
FROM `contacts` AS c
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u 
ON u.id = uid
HAVING uid >0
```

How can I write the right request?

Comment: Why are you using `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`? Are there user IDs in `contacts` that aren't in `users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to an column alias in the `WHERE` clause of the same `SELECT`, because `WHERE` is used to find the rows before the `SELECT` clause operates on them. Put that into a subquery.

```
SELECT u.email, c.uid
FROM (SELECT CASE
                WHEN from_user_id = '301' THEN to_user_id
                ELSE from_user_id
             END AS uid
      FROM contacts
      WHERE from_user_id = '301' OR to_user_id = '301') AS c'
LEFT JOIN users AS u
ON u.id = c.uid
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very important that you help people!